# Displaying decimals only if they are not equal to 0. C++

Tags: c++, decimalformat

My doubles are:

```
32943.14
55772.04
15310.58
```

My output should be:

```
32943.1
55772
15310.6
```

I tried the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    double numbers[3] = { 32943.14, 55772.04, 15310.58 };
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        cout << setprecision (1) << fixed << numbers[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It did not work. What is the best way to get required output?

Comment: Do you know what a `std::ostringstream` is, how it works, and how to use it?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik no, I'm new to C++. What are you suggesting?

Comment: Perform your output on a `std::ostringstream` instead of `std::cout`, then grab the resulting string from the stringstream and parse it from the right-hand side, removing any zeroes until you reach a non-zero or eat the decimal separator. Note that the separator character might not be `.` -- that is dependent on the locale.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError That doesn't work most of the time. You still can't represent most binary fractions in decimal, or decimal fractions in binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you actually assign the result to a double variable, you get the desired output.

```cpp
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  double numbers[3] = {32943.14, 55772.04, 15310.58};
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    stringstream ss;
    ss << fixed << setprecision(1) << numbers[i];
    double n = stod(ss.str());
    cout << n << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Remember that `fixed << setprecision(1)` are only formatting the `numbers[i]` to be displayed. If you then turn the formatted string, e.g., `"123.0"` back to a double, then it is automatically printed as `123`.

Comment: note though that `std::cout` is not in `fixed` mode, but rather `defaultfloat` mode - so you'll get scientific notation for larger double values: [godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/YaYr5P6h9) - e.g. `1531015310.58` would be printed as `1.53102e+09` with this method (instead of `1531015310.6`)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using `<cstdio>` simply outputting with `%g` will do what you want. Without a precision for `%g`, it is taken as `1` and only non-zero decimals are output, e.g.

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    
    double numbers[3] = { 32943.14, 55772.04, 15310.58 };
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        printf ("%g\n", numbers[i]);
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Compiled with:

```
 g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++20 -Ofast -o bin/precision1-if-nonzero-stdio precision1-if-nonzero-stdio.cpp
```

```
$ ./bin/precision1-if-nonzero-stdio
32943.1
55772
15310.6
```

(not to mention the assembler code being 1800% smaller...)

Comment: note that this won't work correctly for smaller or larger numbers. For smaller numbers it would print more than 1 decimal place (e.g. `0.1423` would be printed as `0.1423` instead of `0.1`) and large numbers will be printed in scientific notation instead of fixed (e.g. `6755234.43` would be printed as `6.75523e+06` instead of `6755234.4`). [godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/ffExoezra) - also `%g` is the [default output mode](https://eel.is/c++draft/facet.num.put.virtuals#tab:facet.num.put.fp) of c++ iostreams, so `std::cout << numbers[i] << std::endl;` would have the same effect.